# Problem with singleton from xml parser. afternavigation

Tags: iphone, xml, uitableview, nsarray

after parse xml.  xml attributes data i stored in NSMutableArray *anArray;  which is in MyAppDelegate.  I used anArray in MyAppDelegate.

For my xml i do have One root Tag and N number Child tag.

my xml example:

```
  <root>
    <child name1="",name2="",name3=""/>
    <child name1="",name2="",name3=""/>
    <child name1="",name2="",name3=""/>
    </root>
```

i parsed data perfectly and i displayed name1 on table View.....
When i navigated it used didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  And i loaded the nib file.  which has tableview IBOutlet. i set class for my nib....datasource and delegate to the file owner every thing work perfectly.  navigation stuff work perfectly....

now i need load data into second nib file tableview  name2 and name3  values. but it displaying only name2 values. what to do .. I used the above code in my controller class. for second nib.

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
        return [appDelegate.anArray count]; 
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }


        DetailsView *detailsview=[appDelegate.anArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        switch (indexPath.section) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text=detailsview.name1;
                break;
                case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text=detailsview.name2;
                    break;
                            default:
                break;
    }
    return cell;
    }
```

Comment: how to display selected tag values on my tableview  Thanks in advance

Comment: Want to display.... selected tag. name1 i selected only first tag child name1 value display... what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method `numberOfSectionsInTableView` you say that your table view has only one section. Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you do a switch on the section. Based on the code above, only name1 should be displayed, because your section will always be 0.